# Control C++ Standard Revision in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I am using the visual studio 2019  for my C++ projects, I wanted to control the C++ version when compiling. I have changed it from "project > properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language standard > "

It was on `Default (ISO C++14 Standard)`

I used this to check the version:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << __cplusplus << endl;
}
```

But the output is `199711`

I changed the C++ language standard to `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)`

But still the output of `__cplusplus` is always `199711`

Any idea?

Comment: You need an additional option. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160):

> The __cplusplus preprocessor macro is commonly used to report support
> for a particular version of the C++ standard. Because lots of existing
> code appears to depend on the value of this macro matching "199711L",
> the compiler does not change the value of the macro unless you
> explicitly opt-in by using the /Zc:__cplusplus compiler option. The
> /Zc:__cplusplus option is available starting in Visual Studio 2017
> version 15.7, and is off by default. In earlier versions of Visual
> Studio, and by default, or if /Zc:__cplusplus- is specified, Visual
> Studio returns the value "199711L" for the __cplusplus preprocessor
> macro. The /permissive- option does not enable /Zc:__cplusplus.

So, you could  add `/Zc:__cplusplus` or `/Zc:__cplusplus-` to the `Additional options` in `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line`.